# Using onclick to change a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript needs to change a variable inside a function if a radio button is clicked. I have tried couple of methods - if else statement being one of them, but nothing has worked so far.

In my last try I tried to execute a function on click where it would reset my variable declared earlier in the first function.

The whole purpose of code is to generate a random password with an option to use special symbols.

It is also meant to be a Chrome extension, so the use of inline code is forbidden.

```
<html>
    <br>
    <h1>Set the number of characters</h1>
    <input id="num"  type = "number" value = "20" name = "value"><br><br>
    
    <form>
    <input type="radio" type = "text"  id="spec_symb" name="symbols" value="specialSymbols">
    <label for="spec_symb">Use special symbols</label><br>
</form>
<button id="click">Generate</button><br>
    <p id="text" ></p>
    
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="pass.js"></script>
    
</html>
```

```
function pass(length) {
    var passw = "";
    var symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    document.getElementById("spec_symb").onclick = function(){func()};
    function func(){window.symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_"
 };
 var slength = symbols.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       passw = passw + symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * slength));
    }
    return passw;}
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
 function myFunction(){
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = passw(document.getElementById("num").value);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your if/else statement with document.getElementById('spec_symb').checked

That should get you in the direction you want to go.

Comment: I was using ```document.getElementById('spec_symb').clicked == true``` before, but```document.getElementById('spec_symb').checked == true``` actually works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you're calling the `pass()` function you're assigning the `symbols` variable the value `ABC..`, you're expecting the user to click on the `#spec_symb` at the same time the function is called (and thats close to impossible). Instead of doing that you should verify wheater the input is checked or not and then assign it a new value, in your case you can just add to the old string, like the example below.

```js
document.querySelector("#pass").onclick = () => {
  let chars = "ABC...";
  if (document.querySelector("#input").checked)
    chars += "#@$";
  console.log(chars);
};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="checkbox" />
<button id="pass">Result</button>
```

I've changed from radio to checkbox so you can unmark it.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is a bit off and you are attempting to call the `passw` function, which doesn't exist.

You should also not be setting `symbols` inside the `pass` function. Set it to the default first and possibly override it if the checkbox gets checked.

You should also probably be using a checkbox instead of a radio button, because once the radio button is checked, there's no way to uncheck it.

I think this is what you are after:

```js
// Set reference to DOM elements just once, not in the functions
const input = document.getElementById("num");
const output = document.getElementById("text");
const special = document.getElementById("spec_symb");

special.addEventListener("click", func);
document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

// Set the symbols to the default set of characters
let symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
 
function func(){
  // Override the symbols if the checkbox was checked.
  if(special.checked){
    symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_";
  } else {
    symbols = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  }
}

function myFunction(){
  output.textContent = pass(input.value);
}

function pass(length) {
  var passw = "";
  
  var slength = symbols.length;
  for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    passw = passw + symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * slength));
  }
  return passw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Set the number of characters</h1>
<input id="num"  type = "number" value = "20" name = "value"><br><br>
    
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="spec_symb" name="symbols" value="specialSymbols">
  <label for="spec_symb">Use special symbols</label><br>
</form>
<button id="click">Generate</button>
<p id="text" ></p>
```